# iCloudKeyChainにアイテムを追加したい

Tags: swift, macos, swift5

今まで`SecKeychainAddGenericPassword`しか使ったことがないのですが、
今回、`iCloudKeyChain`にGenericPassword(KeyChain Accessで見るとKindがapplication password)を追加したく、以下のようなコードを書いてみました

```swift
let token: String = "0123456789"
let query: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecReturnPersistentRef as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,
    kSecAttrSynchronizable as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecAttrAccount as String: "Charleston" as NSString,
    kSecAttrService as String: "Charleston Safe Storage" as NSString
    kSecValueData as String: token as NSString
        ]
var result: AnyObject?
let resultCode: OSStatus = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
    SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, $0)
}
```

が、`resultCode`が`-50`と

> errSecParam

と、パラメーターが間違っていると怒られてしまいます。
どんな項目が不足しているかわかる方、お教え下さい。
Sigining & Capabilitiesには`Keychain Shareing`を有効にしており、
システム環境設定のiCloud→KeyChainはオンになっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずNSStringやStringは直接Keychain APIに格納するデータとして渡せません。
すべてNSDataとして渡す必要があります。

```swift
kSecValueData as String: token.data(using: .utf8)! as NSData
```

なので、上記の行をこのように書き換えると、ひとまず現在のエラーは解消してKeychainへ書き込めるはずです。

Comment: `kSecAttrAccount`が余計だったみたいです。